# Find the controller that a route is hitting in a Sonata project

Tags: php, symfony, sonata

I am working on a project based on Symfony 2.7 and the Sonata admin bundle. The project uses a workflow that includes an "unpublish" step. I want to modify the logic of that step.

Running `app/console debug:router | grep unpublish` gives me this:

```
admin_mycompany_app_video_unpublish                                 ANY      ANY    ANY  /admin/mycompany/app/video/{id}/unpublish/
```

... and searching for `admin_mycompany_app_video_unpublish` in my codebase finds only the following in `appDevDebugProjectContainerUrlMatcher.php`:

```
return $this->redirect($pathinfo.'/', 'admin_mycompany_app_video_unpublish');
```

So the route exists, but I cannot seem to find what controller it's pointing at.

Any suggestions for finding that controller?

Comment: Try `grep -r unpublish src/ | grep Controller`.

Comment: `app/console router:match /admin/exozet/app/video/123/unpublish` should do the trick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find it in getRoutes() method of VideoAdmin it’s calculated on the fly based on naming conventions

The corresponding code should be in VideoAdminController.

Hope it helps